# Removing duplicates in xslt based on two different child node values

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, grouping

Am trying to generate a XSLT for the below requirement.

I have used generate-id and Key based on sequenceNumber |Type|Value and it is deleting the Duplicate under Items/Item.

But not sure how can i check for duplicate StateType along with the same and remove only the Item which satisfy both the conditions.

So I want to Remove the  under  which contains duplicate values based duplicate values of StateType ( basically both are under different parents.)

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <Containers>
    <Container>
     <DetailContainer>
      <Items>
       <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <Type>Property</Type>
        <Value>100</Value>
       </Item>
       <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
        <Type>Insurance</Type>
        <Value>200</Value>
       </Item>
      </Items>
      <Property>
       <ID>1</ID>
       <Date>2019-03-12</Date>
      </Property>
     <DetailContainer>
     <State>
      <StateType>Current</StateType>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Date>2019-03-12</Date>
     </State>
    </Container>
    <Container>
     <DetailContainer>
      <Items>
       <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>3</SequenceNumber>
        <Type>Property</Type>
        <Value>600</Value>
       </Item>
       <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>4</SequenceNumber>
        <Type>Insurance</Type>
        <Value>500</Value>
       </Item>
      </Items>
      <Property>
       <ID>2</ID>
       <Date>2017-07-12</Date>
      </Property>
     </DetailContainer>
     <State>
      <StateType>Previous</StateType>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Date>2019-03-12</Date>
     </State>
    </Container>
    <Container>
     <DetailContainer>
      <Items>
       <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <Type>Property</Type>
        <Value>100</Value>
       </Item>
       <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
        <Type>Insurance</Type>
        <Value>200</Value>
       </Item>
      </Items>
      <Property>
       <ID>2</ID>
       <Date>2019-03-12</Date>
      </Property>
     </DetailContainer>
     <State>
      <StateType>Current</StateType>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Date>2019-03-12</Date>
     </State>
    </Container>
    </Containers>
```

Expected Output -

```
    <Containers>
    <Container>
     <DetailContainer>
      <Items>
       <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <Type>Property</Type>
        <Value>100</Value>
       </Item>
       <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
        <Type>Insurance</Type>
        <Value>200</Value>
       </Item>
      </Items>
      <Property>
       <ID>1</ID>
       <Date>2019-03-12</Date>
      </Property>
     </DetailContainer>
     <State>
      <StateType>Current</StateType>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Date>2019-03-12</Date>
     </State>
    </Container>
    <Container>
     <DetailContainer>
      <Items>
       <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>3</SequenceNumber>
        <Type>Property</Type>
        <Value>600</Value>
       </Item>
       <Item>
        <SequenceNumber>4</SequenceNumber>
        <Type>Insurance</Type>
        <Value>500</Value>
       </Item>
      </Items>
      <Property>
       <ID>2</ID>
       <Date>2017-07-12</Date>
      </Property>
    </DetailContainer>
     <State>
      <StateType>Previous</StateType>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Date>2019-03-12</Date>
     </State>
    </Container>
    <Container>
     <DetailContainer>
      <Items>

      </Items>
      <Property>
       <ID>2</ID>
       <Date>2019-03-12</Date>
      </Property>
     </DetailContainer>
     <State>
      <StateType>Current</StateType>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Date>2019-03-12</Date>
     </State>
    </Container>
    </Containers>



------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Code to Remove Duplicate Item -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="ItemDup" match="Item" use="concat(SequenceNumber,'|',Type,'|', Value)" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-template select="node()|@*" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[generate-id(key('ItemDup',concat(SequenceNumber,'|',Type,'|', Value))[1])]">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-template/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: For grouping questions the solution is going to be different for XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, so please say which version. Also please show your best attempt, then we can see what you know already and where you got stuck.

Comment: @Michael Kay, I have pasted the XSLT(1.0) am using to remove the Item duplicate. But am stuck on how to define another key for State and delete Item based on this one.

Comment: With `Item` element as context node, the ralative path to `StateType` element would be `parent::Items/parent::DetailContainer/parent::Container/child::State/child::StateType` or abbreviated `../../../State/StateType`

Comment: Please fix your examples to be well-formed XML documents.

Comment: removing duplicate  <Item> Based on two different composite key as mentioned above is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you asked for. You are trying to remove duplicated based on `concat(SequenceNumber,'|', Type,'|', Value)`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict">


    <xsl:key name="ItemDup" match="Item" use="concat(SequenceNumber,'|', Type,'|', Value)" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item[generate-id() != generate-id(key('ItemDup', concat(SequenceNumber, '|', Type, '|', Value))[1])]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I want to remove duplicate based on concat(SequenceNumber ,’|’,Type,’|’,Value) when the State/StateType  also is a duplicate Else do not remove.